# Both options run in guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.3

So I'm very new to programing and I'm using Python (v3.33) to create little programs like so:

```
option = input('What Game Would You Like To Play? A, B, C, or D? ')
option == 'A'
guess = int(input('Guess a number: '))
while True:
    while guess != 100:
        if guess > 100:
            print('Too High... Try Again')
        if guess < 100:
            print('Too Low... Try Again')
        guess = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    if guess == 100:
        print('You Win')
        break

option == 'B'
guess = int(input('Guess a number: '))
while True:
    while guess != 50:
        if guess > 50:
            print('Too High...Try Again')
        if guess < 50:
            print('Too Low... Try Again')
            guess = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    if guess == 50:
        print('You Win')
        break
```

Here is my problem- I want the user to be able to select 'A' or 'B' (I will get to adding 'C' and 'D' but want to fix problems first) but the program takes the user through 'A' automatically and then to 'B': How do I get it so user can select 'A' and 'B'. 
Also, how do I make it so user can have option to say 'Yes' or 'No' if they want to run it again.
Thanks

Comment: If you want more people to help, change your question title to something related to the problem.

Comment: if option == 'A': may be?

Comment: Further down the line, you can also add in some logic for how you'd handle cases where the user entered something you didn't anticipate...like if they entered "z" for yes/no =b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the whole thing in a while loop:

```
while True:

    option = input('What Game Would You Like To Play? A, B, C, or D (Q to quit)? ').upper() # this can accept both lower and upper case input

    if option == 'Q': 
        break

    elif option == 'A': 
        Do some code 

    elif option == 'B':
        Do some code

    elif option == 'C':
        Do some code

    elif option == 'D':
        Do some code

    else:
        print ("You didn't enter a valid choice!")
```

**About your code:**

```
option == 'A'
```

that line simply tests whether option is equal to 'A'. It returns a `True` or a `False`.
You want to test for options actual value. Hence the `if` statements above.

Your code is just running through all scenarios because you haven't provided the conditions under which things should happen. Only when `option == 'A'` should code for that situation be run. Only when `option == 'D'` should code for that be run. And only when `option == 'Q'` should the main loop break. This is a good example of when to use the `if` statement.

**EDIT:**

With regards to your comment, you could do the following:

```
option = input('What Game Would You Like To Play? A, B, C, or D (Q to quit)? ')
if option == 'a': # upper is gone, you can specify upper or lower case 'manually'
    do this
if option == 'A':
    do this
```

**Or**

```
if option in ['a', 'A']: # this basically same effect as my original answer
       do something
```

check out how the `str.upper()` method works [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_upper.htm)

Comment: Thank you.  Quickly what does '.upper()' mean?

Comment: It means that even if someone enters a lowercase letter, it is converted to the upper case for the check. So if they enter 'b' or 'q'. It becomes 'B' or 'Q'.

Comment: @user3291108, try to get used to sites like http://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=upper&check_keywords=yes&area=default, they will help now and then.

Comment: @user3291108 in the python interpreter type 'a'.upper() and hit enter, and try 'B'.lower() and hit enter. It will show you the result

Comment: @user3291108 I edited the post. I added .upper() to the initial option question so you don't have to retype it for each if statement. It looks a lot cleaner

Comment: @Totem For future use, can I make the command have two inputs- like 'a' and 'A'.  Also, do I have to use one if statement then use the rest as elif?

Comment: you don't have to use elif at all. They could all be standalone if statments if you want. I just thought it was handier to use the elifs, as then you could include the final else. For the inputs, you could of course have 'a' and/or 'A'. But why would you do that? with upper() the letter is accepted whether it is input as upper or lower case. However, if you want to have to different situations depending on whether 'a' or 'A' was input, then you could do that. I will do a quick post update.

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question or not

Comment: Yes that answers my question.  I like the .upper(), but I was not sure how to do multiple inputs for the same command.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: there is also .lower()

Answer (score 1):

It takes you through both options because you are not using a check for the option.

While your code is *technically* checking `option == 'A'` and then later `option == 'B'`, it's not checking one or the other and not doing anything with that check.

Instead you would want:

```
option = input('What Game Would You Like To Play? A, B, C, or D? ')

if option == 'A':
    guess = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    ....
    break
elif option == 'B':
    guess = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    ....
    break
```

The `elif` is there instead of `else` so you have room to add code for options C and D.